# How to interpret Trinamic driver continuous debug reporting?

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver, tmc2130

In Marlin one can enable [continuous debug reporting of Trinamic drivers](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M122.html) with the command

`M122 S1`

This sends lines similar to the following over the serial connection:

```
X:93/28/0||    Y:35/14/-|IF|   Z:54/28/0||    E:176/25/0||
```

Each driver appears to report three integer values and some flags. I understand the `F` flag indicates an error state, for example the overtemperature pre-warn condition (OTPW).

What do the other values mean? How can this information be interpreted to debug printing problems or improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

In the Marlin source code I found the function responsible for the report logs: `report_polled_driver_data` in `Marlin/src/feature/tmc_util.cpp`.

The values indicated appear to be:

```
<Axis>:<PWM scale>/<Current scale>/<StallGuard>|<Flags>|<OTPW count>
```

Where possible flags are as follows (where “debug” indicates that they only appear if `TMC_DEBUG` is enabled):

- E: **E**rror
- O: **O**ver-temperature
- W: over-temperature pre-**W**arning
- G: stall**G**uard (debug)
- T: stealth**C**hop (debug)
- I: standst**I**ll (debug)
- F: otpw **F**lag